How to fix XYDataset error when creating a bar graph in Java?
I am trying to create an example graph for a different project. The issue is that I am getting the error:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable code

regarding this line:
 dataset.addSeries(series); 

in this code:
public class Graphs extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Graphs
     */
    public Graphs() {
    initComponents();
    XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Weight Progress");
    int zeropoint = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        series.add(i, i);
        zeropoint = i;
    }
    
    XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
    dataset.addSeries(series);
    
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("Name", "Week", "Time", dataset);
    ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    chartPanel.setSize(500, 500);
    jPanel1.add(chartPanel); // Add chartPanel to jPanel1
    jPanel1.revalidate();
    jPanel1.repaint();
}

This code takes place in a JForm in Netbeans IDE.
I manipulated the values used to initialize the series, but it did not work.

You need to post the full error message verbatim

posted code, after adding some missing parts (jPanel1, initComponents(), ...) is working here - "Uncompilable code" usually indicates an ignored compiler error - check the compiler output or IDE for compilation errors

If this is not a duplicate, please [edit] your question to show your revised approach.

The recently released NetBeans 22 fixed a number of internal parsing errors discussed here.

Instead of replacing the panel in your top-level container, simply update or replace the chart's dataset, for example.
